# Homemade metal cover for Arduino temperature sensor

Tags: sensors

I have one **ds18b20 temperature sensor** for [this project](https://github.com/Startup-Data/UN-Hakim-PCR/tree/main/Arduino/Temperature), but **I don't have the metal cover** for it like shown below:
[image]

So if possible I asked here to have your intelligence for finding some homemade alternative as metal cover for covering this sensor (Metal Covers are better).

**Update:**

If the required tools not have high price I can buy or borrow it, but I have [the basic mechanical tools](https://www.google.com/search?q=basic%20mechanical%20toools%20at%20ordinary%20home&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjtgMytjtPxAhW7ybsIHZIpBWYQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=basic%20mechanical%20toools%20at%20ordinary%20home&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQA1C4SFjTkQFgg5QBaARwAHgAgAGEAogB-RGSAQUwLjcuNJgBAKABAaoBC2d3cy13aXotaW1nwAEB&sclient=img&ei=2r7mYO2rJLuT7_UPktOUsAY&bih=888&biw=1853#imgrc=nN-7UzpnWyFHyM) in my home, like shown at below:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Homemade with what equipment? I have a lathe at home for example... Not enough information in your question to be very helpful

Comment: Thanks, @Jonathan_R_Swift, I have basic mechanical tools in my home and updated the question based on your comment.

Comment: We need a lot more info. What is the purpose of the metal cover? Must it be waterproof; does it have to withstand pressure, or corrosives?  how large can the diameter be and still  fit into whatever you're going to use it for?  For one extreme, you could wrap the thermistor in aluminum foil; for the other you'd need high-grade stainless with a silicone seal at the wiring interface.

Comment: Thanks, @Carl_Witthoft, I need it for ordinary usage, so I only need waterproof, and dot past high pressure on it. Also, the proper size is shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YTnq.png) which is 6 mm*50 mm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you don't have much fabrication equipment at home you will need to find the metal casing. There are many miscellaneous objects that might work, for example a fired  .22 case, or maybe a piece of copper tube with one end soldered shut.

Once you've got that, solder a cable onto your sensor, and then pot it in the metal case using 2 part epoxy. Thermal epoxy would be ideal, but it's expensive and it probably will work fine with regular epoxy.